# BFFs or BFF's? Which one is right?

Tags: apostrophe

Here's the sentence - We Put These BFF's to the test.

Is this correct or wrong and why?

Comment: Fred and Linda are both BFFs.  That is my BFF's car.

Answer (score 0):

BFFs is correct as it is the plural form of BFF. An apostrophe only goes before the "s" when

1. To show ownership of a thing.

   > This is John's house
2. To shorten: something + "is".

   > John is in the military --> John's in the military